# My golang server code is panicking and I don't know why

Tags: go

I was working on a golang project I have been trying to perfect for the last 2 weeks and the server runs for like 5 seconds but after which point the terminal says my code panicked. I have been trying to fix it for almost an hour and no progress is being made. It is a basic server which runs on 'localhost:7070' and also renders a html file. I have used a framework called gearbox for experimentation and to level up my skill set. If you could fic it for me it would be a great help.

This is my main.go file:

```golang
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    _"net/http"
    gear "github.com/gogearbox/gearbox"
)

type Todo struct {
    Title string
    Done  bool
}

type TodoPageData struct {
    PageTitle string
    Todos     []Todo
}

func main() {
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("layout.html"))
    var Gear = gear.New()
    Gear.Get("/", func(ctx gear.Context) {
        data := TodoPageData{
            PageTitle: "My TODO list",
            Todos: []Todo{
                {Title: "Task 1", Done: false},
                {Title: "Task 2", Done: true},
                {Title: "Task 3", Done: true},
            },
        }
        tmpl.Execute(nil , data)
    })
  Gear.Start(":7070")
}
```

This is my layout.html file:

```
<h1>{{.PageTitle}}</h1>
<ul>
    {{range .Todos}}
        {{if .Done}}
            <li class="done">{{.Title}}</li>
        {{else}}
            <li>{{.Title}}</li>
        {{end}}
    {{end}}
</ul>
```

I tried to make changes to the arguments in every method of the main.go file and also tried to modify my html file. Nothing seems to work and my terminal just shows a panic message.

Comment: Is there a `layout.html` file present?

Comment: You must pass a non-nil io.Writer as the first argument to tmpl.Execute.

Comment: I tried to pass the ctx as the argument but it didn't work. Also there is a layout.html file but I has a typo the index.html is actually the layout.html file

Comment: Looks like passing ctx.Context() should work.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the template object data selection. the parent should be .TodoPageData:

```
<h1>{{.TodoPageData.PageTitle}}</h1>
<ul>
    {{range .TodoPageData.Todos}}
        {{if .Done}}
            <li class="done">{{.Title}}</li>
        {{else}}
            <li>{{.Title}}</li>
        {{end}}
    {{end}}
</ul>
```

Happy coding:)